# angular-slick attributes with capital case

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a carousel with angular-slick (https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick).

Some of the slick settings for the carousel do not seem to work when used as attributes of the slick-directive. These attributes all have one or more capital case letters.

I had to change these attributes to lower case letters in slick.js and in the angular model for slick.js.  For instance to get a custom button for next and previous I had to change prevArrow and NextArrow to prevarrow and nextarrow so i can use it in the following way:

```
<slick  prevarrow='.btn-prev' nextarrow='.btn-next' arrows="true" data="windows">
    <div ng-repeat="window in windows" class="slick-slide">
        <a><img ng-src={{window.imageUrls[0]}}></a>
    </div>
</slick>    
<div class="slider-controls">
     <button class="btn-next">customNext</button>
     <button class="btn-prev">customPrev</button>
</div>
```

Changing the code in the libraries does not seem the right way to get it working. Is there some obvious mistake I made or is this just a limitation to the slick-settings one can use via the slick element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see directives with `capital` case like `nextArrow`, you must use them as

```
next-arrow
```

No need to change the library code. Angular follows same convention as CSS. When there is a capital cased directive `prevArrow`, in your HTML if you want to reference it, use `prev-arrow`.

Best example for it is:

```
ng-app
```

In your HTML you might have used it as `ng-app` but if you check it in the angular code, it will be `ngApp`